# Power broker safe shell or full shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script

I am looking for a script which we can pass as an argument to the pbrun command.

Eg:

```
Login: test1
Passwd: xxxxxxx

Welcome to Solaris 10 gcmsys01

$ pbrun sysadmins safeksh
```

Here sysadmins is the group-name and safeksh is a script which will disable any harmful commands like rm, init 6, format etc etc., similarly, there should be a fullksh script which will allow full shell access to the server (can execute any root commands without any restriction). This script is to overcome any unwanted outages due to some harmful commands.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't really disable harmful commands, because most commands can be harmful if applied to the wrong object (e.g. `echo bad >/dev/w0d0` (or whatever a disk device is called under Solaris)). You need to allow only the commands that you consider safe. Which commands do you want to allow?

Answer (score 1):

You should acquire `rssh', the restricted shell
You can follow the restriction guides mentioned above, they're all rather self-explanatory, and simple to follow. implement terminal options.see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Restricted-Shell) for restricted shell and for more option see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login) thread in stackoverflow